# How do I properly return a user object from firebase sign using an async thunk and redux slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication

After sign in, I wan to return the user object to the slice, but I keep getting an error, about non serializable data, how do I properly configure this ?
[image]

```
export const updateProfileAsync = createAsyncThunk('user/updateProfile', async(user:any, 
profile:any)=>{
const response = await  updateProfile(user,profile)

return response.user
})
```

interface

```
interface userState {
user:User 
}
```

in my slice,

```
extraReducers:(builder) => {
    builder.addCase(loginAsync.pending, (state,action)=>{
        console.log('pending')
        state.loading = 'pending'
    })
    builder.addCase(loginAsync.fulfilled, (state,action)=>{
        state.loading = 'succeeded'
        console.log('logged in')
        console.log(action.payload)
        state.loginError = ''
    })  
    builder.addCase(loginAsync.rejected, (state,action)=>{
        state.loginError = action.error.message
        state.loading = 'failed'
        console.log('failed')
    })
```

Comment: Something in `response.user` is non-serializable. What do you actually need to keep and store in state from that object reference? Please [edit] to provide more details what you are trying to accompish.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your object `user.user` is not aserializable, but data that you return to the slice should be [aserializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Serializable_object).

you can have a look [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data) how to work with Non-Serializable data in Redux.
see also [Use with React-Redux-Firebase](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-react-redux-firebase)